# spring-data-solr: no value for field 1 in solrinputdocument

Tags: spring-boot, solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to index some data in solrcloud. I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-solr and below is my code:

- The application.yaml :

```
spring:
  data:
    solr:
      host: http://default-example-solrcloud.ing.local.domain/solr
      core: mycollection
```

- The document I want to save:

```
@SolrDocument(collection = "mycollection")
public class MyDocument {

    @Id
    @Indexed(name = "id", type = "string")
    private String id;

    @Indexed(name = "content", type = "text_general")
    private String content;

    //...
}
```

- The client code:

```
MyDocument document = new MyDocument();
document.setId("1");
document.setContent("This is the content of the document.");
myDocumentRepository.save(document);
```

Did I miss some steps?

I expected the document to be saved. Instead I receive the error:
DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error from server at http://default-example-solrcloud.ing.local.domain/solr:
**No value for field 1 in SolrInputDocument(fields: [id=1, ...])**